# Add a key with multiple values to nested JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, regex

I have a JSON-variable like this:

```
json_file = {

 "Line 1": [
    {"HFGR62"},
    {"K6RTFV"},
    {"86G37F"}
 ],

 "Line 2": [
    {"FG3RH5"},
    {"45H4H4"},
    {"H4HTH5"}
 ]

}
```

And a string that looks like this:

```
string = "{Line 3} Bla bla bla <F3465> <G46H6> bla bla bla <4H6HH> bla <4TH56> bla bla <G4H65>"
```

I need to first extract the text "Line 3" and append it as a key to json_file above, after that I need to find all numbers/letters inside "<>" and append these as values.

I have tried the following:

```
line = re.match('{(.+?)}', string)
json_file[line.group(1)] = json_file

brackets = re.findall('<(.+?)>', string)
for element in brackets:
   json_file[line.group(1)] = ({element})
```

The script adds a new key, but only the last one...

Any ideas?

Comment: That ain't a valid *JSON* (`{"HFGR62"}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Use `regex` (regular expression) + `json` libraries to correct the incorrectly formatted json file.

The json file is not properly structured as a json. So, the easiest fix will be to substitute each `{"ABCXYZ"}` with `{"ABCXYZ": null}`. This will allow you to read it in as a json file using `json` library as shown below.

We use `re.sub()` to substitute all such occurrences in your json file.

**Note**: I did not change the structure from a `list of {<something>}` to a `list of <something>` just to avoid the scenario, if you have any entry where it is like `{<something>: <somevalue>}`.

```py
import re # regex
import json
ss = re.sub(r'{(".*?")}', r'{\1: null}', s)
print(ss)
# Load as json
d = json.loads(ss)
print(d)
```

**Output**:

```sh
## print(ss)
{

 "Line 1": [
    {"HFGR62": null},
    {"K6RTFV": null},
    {"86G37F": null}
 ],

 "Line 2": [
    {"FG3RH5": null},
    {"45H4H4": null},
    {"H4HTH5": null}
 ]

}

## print(d)

{'Line 1': [{'HFGR62': None}, {'K6RTFV': None}, {'86G37F': None}],
 'Line 2': [{'FG3RH5': None}, {'45H4H4': None}, {'H4HTH5': None}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`set()` isn't valid JSON type, use simple string instead:

```
string = "{Line 3} Bla bla bla <F3465> <G46H6> bla bla bla <4H6HH> bla <4TH56> bla bla <G4H65>"

current_key = ''
for k, v in re.findall(r'{(.*?)}|<(.*?)>', string):
    if k:
        json_file[k] = []
        current_key = k
    else:
        json_file[current_key].append(v)

import json
print(json.dumps(json_file, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Line 1": [
        "HFGR62",
        "K6RTFV",
        "86G37F"
    ],
    "Line 2": [
        "FG3RH5",
        "45H4H4",
        "H4HTH5"
    ],
    "Line 3": [
        "F3465",
        "G46H6",
        "4H6HH",
        "4TH56",
        "G4H65"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
line = re.match('{(.+?)}', string)
#json_file[line.group(1)] = json_file COMMENT/DELETE THIS LINE!!!

brackets = re.findall('<(.+?)>', string)
for element in brackets:
    if line.group(1) in json_file:
        json_file[line.group(1)].append({element})
    else:
        json_file[line.group(1)] = [{element}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use re.findall('RegexString',variable)

```
>>> string = "{Line 3} Bla bla bla <F3465> <G46H6> bla bla bla <4H6HH> bla <4TH56> bla 
bla <G4H65> {Line 2}"
>>> import re
>>> line = re.findall('{(.+?)}', string)
>>> print(line)
['Line 3', 'Line 2']
>>> lineTemp = re.match('{(.+?)}', string)
>>> print(lineTemp.groups())
('Line 3',)
>>>
```

**re.match()** function will search the regular expression pattern and return the first occurrence. This method checks for a match only at the beginning of the string. So, if a match is found in the first line, it returns the match object. But if a match is found in some other line, it returns null.